# BUILD ERROR when running Apache Mahout example

Tags: java, machine-learning, mahout

I just installed Hadoop and Mahout and now I want to try running some example dataset with Mahout.

I followed the example from here: https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/recommendationexamples.html
And I tried the MovieLens example with this syntax:

```
mvn -q exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.example.grouplens.GroupLensRecommenderEvaluatorRunner" -Dexec.args="-i temp/ml-1m/ml-1m/ratings.dat"
```

But it just didn't work. Moreover, it just says [ERROR] BUILD ERROR.
My question, how can I see the errors log and how can I fix it?

Comment: please post the full error.

Comment: That was the full error message. "[ERROR] BUILD ERROR". Is there a way to extend this error message?

Comment: what have you done to install Mahout? Have you compiled the examples?

Comment: I have compiled & installed Mahout itself, and yes, I have compiled the examples. In general I've followed the steps here: https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/buildingmahout.html

Answer (score 0):

you should escape the `-q`. the command is `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.example.grouplens.GroupLensRecommenderEvaluatorRunner" -Dexec.args="-i temp/ml-1m/ml-1m/ratings.dat"`
I once have the error because the file path is wrong, you can check it!